# changing a sprite width when playing a reel using Crafty.js

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

can anyone help me with this : http://jsfiddle.net/B5UsC/20/

you can see that the sprite animation is not rendering correctly when the reel is in the last frame when animating `Hardpunch` is it possible to change the character width when playing a specific frame ? like you see my spritesheet does not contain a static width and height so it's a bit confusing for me

**THE CODE :**

```
// initialize the sprite
Crafty.sprite("http://i.imgur.com/bkYVEe5.png", {
    Ryu: [0, 0, plrw, plrh]
});

// initialize the component
Crafty.c("RyuAnimation", {
    init: function () {
        this.requires("SpriteAnimation,Keyboard")
        .addComponent("Ryu")
        .reel('idle', 300, [
            [0, 0],
            [plrw * 1, 0],
            [plrw * 2, 0],
            [plrw * 3, 0]
        ])
        .reel('punch', 300, [
            [plrw + 12, plrh],
            [plrw * 2 + 15, plrh]
        ])
        .reel('Hardpunch', 300, [
            [plrw * 3 - 25, plrh],
            [plrw * 4 + 32, plrh],
            [(plrw + 19) * 5 - 38, plrh]
        ]); //
        this.animate("idle", -1);

    }

    // creating the player 
    plr1 = Crafty.e("2D,Canvas,RyuAnimation")
    .attr({
    x: 15,
    y: ch - 100
})
.start(3);
this.bind('KeyDown', function () {
    if (this.isDown('A')) {
        if (!this.isPlaying("Hardpunch")) {
            this.pauseAnimation().animate("Hardpunch", 1);
        }
    } else {
        this.stop();
    }

});
```

I read about handling complex sprite sheet with different width and height and all the answers was about creating evenly sized boxes for all sprites like this example here : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48225/how-do-i-support-animation-with-frames-of-different-sizes  but i actually couldn't understand what the mean by that and how would i do it they didn't provide an example . what is `evenly sized boxes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evenly sized boxes mean, every frame has to be evenly sized. In your case, every frame has different width. It would be hard to specify every frame's width manually, in fact I don't know how to do that in craftyjs. Your best solution would be cut all frames, and put them in evenly sized boxes with padding. Check out this link for a related discussion. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/craftyjs/eN9KTAxieSI

Comment: i did read that post before you sir have posted your answer but i am still confuse .what i understand is re-sizing every frame in the  entire spritesheet to a static width and height in some editor tool right ? but that can take a lot of time

Comment: Yes, but there is no workaround, think about it, the alternative solution is to manually specify every frame's width and starting position, and crafty doesn't even support it. So there is no feasible solution than padding every frame in `evenly sized boxes` manually. @Sora, accept please.